# XCode Leak profiler - Transient memory keeps going up but persistent memory is constant

Tags: xcode, memory, memory-leaks, opencl, profiler

I'm creating a program that uses openCL in XCode (C++ host, on El Capitan) and the openCL runs on a continuous loop. When profiling my program's memory usage, the persistent memory stays the same but the transient memory is constantly going up, probably due to the fact that I'm constantly enqueuing openCL kernels which requires memory.

Here are some screenshots to show what I mean:

[image]

[image]

These are two images from XCode's heap allocator tool of my program running shown here in chronological order. As you can see the "persistent bytes" remains constant at 184.13MB while the "transient" memory keeps rising.

**So my question(s) here is....**

is this something to be concerned about? Are these considered memory leaks? If I let my program continue running indefinitely would I run out of memory eventually? Or is "transient memory" an irrelevant statistic?

It's a bit confusing because even when not running the profiler...xcode shows the memory usage to constantly be going up. In the image below, the "memory" field number continually goes up which is what originally gave me cause for alarm...but it now seems like it's just going up because the transient memory is going up.

So what do I do?

[image]

Comment: It's been 3 years now with no answers/suggestions. Could you share your analysis?